# Using php array in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I used the latest javascript fullCalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/) on a wordpress webpage to be able to display appointments of a wordress my users. So far the Callendar shows up on the page. Now I want to get the appointments from the db and display them in the Calendar.

If I create an array in php, with the appointments to display as a string, the appoinment shows up in the calendar.

Example:

```
    $events = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_projekt_calendar WHERE calendar_author=$uid");

    foreach($events AS $event){
        
        $array['title']= 'rtrt';
        $array['start']= '2020-08-10 10:00:00';
        $array['end']  = '2020-08-10 11:00:00';

   }
echo json_encode($array);
```

But if I use the query results to show the appointment it doesent work (query works well!):

```
    foreach($events AS $event){
        
        $array['title']= $event_array->calendar_title;
        $array['start']= $event_array->calendar_startdate .' '.$event_array->calendar_starttime;
        $array['end']  = $event_array->calendar_enddate .' '.$event_array->calendar_endtime;;

   }
    echo json_encode($array);
```

This is how my calendar looks like:

```
    <script>
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var initialLocaleCode = 'de';
    var localeSelectorEl = document.getElementById('locale-selector');  
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        
              var date = new Date();
              var d = date.getDate();
              var m = date.getMonth();
              var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        
      height: '100%',
      expandRows: true,
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
      },
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',    
      locale: initialLocaleCode,
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      selectable: true,
      nowIndicator: true,
      dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: {
          url: "https://mydomainxy.com/wp-content/themes/gambit-child/events.php?uid='<?php // $anwender_id ?>'",
          //url: "https://mydomainxy.com/wp-content/themes/gambit-child/php/get-events.php'",
                   type: 'POST',
                   error: function() {
                     alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
                  
                   }
      }
    });

    calendar.render();
  });

</script>
```

What am I doing wrong or how can I get this to work?

Comment: Every loop you overwrite `$array` value, so it will only display the latest value of your query.

Comment: No, thats not the problem. The Jsons are not empty.  I had checked them already. The delivered Jsons are identical. But the first one works, the second one doesn't work. Here the Examples of the Jsons:
`[ { "title": "test", "start": "2020-08-10T15:00:00-05:00", "end": "2020-08-10T16:00:00-05:00" } ]

[ { "title": "test", "start": "2020-08-10T15:00:00-05:00", "end": "2020-08-10T16:00:00-05:00" } ]`

Comment: An other example-

 this one works:

`$json2.='[ ';
for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){//foreach($events AS $event_array){
 
$json2.=' { "title": "test", "start": "2020-08-10T15:00:00-05:00", "end": "2020-08-10T16:00:00-05:00" } ';
 
if($i<2){
  $json2.=', ';
 }

}
$json2.=' ]';`

But this one doesn't work:

`$json2.='[ ';
for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){//foreach($events AS $event_array){
 
$json2.=' { "title": "'. $e[0] .'", "start": "2020-08-10T15:00:00-05:00", "end": "2020-08-10T16:00:00-05:00" } ';
 
if($i<2){
  $json2.=', ';
 }

}
$json2.=' ]';`

Both of them create the same json.

Comment: Something I don't understand, why do you declare ``foreach($events AS $event)`` if you use ``$event_array``?  Plus, you are overwriting your ``$array`` value, as @FelippeDuarte said.

Comment: you should not be creating JSON by hand like those examples in your comments. use json_encode() (as you've done correctly in your main question).

Comment: I changed the Function to:

 ` $my_events = array();

  foreach($events AS $event_array){
   $my_events[] = array(
    'title' => '56u5', //$event_array->calendar_title;
    'start' => '2020-08-10 10:00:00', //$event_array->calendar_startdate .' '.$event_array->calendar_starttime;
    'end'   => '2020-08-10 11:00:00', //$event_array->calendar_enddate .' '.$event_array->calendar_endtime;
    );
  }

echo json_encode($my_events);`

but it is still not working